# prompting the user for correct input

Tags: ruby

I want this programme to get an array and an integer from the user, then to remove the integer from the array. If the users integer is not in the array I want them to be prompted to enter a new integer that is.
I'm struggling to correct the loop it so the prompt appears if the integer is incorrect

```rb
def enter_integer
  puts 'what would you like to remove from array?'
  interger = gets.chomp
  if array.include?(interger)
    array.delete(interger)
    print array
  end
end

def first_array
  puts 'please enter an array of numbers'
  array = gets.chomp

  array = array.split('')

  puts 'what would you like to remove from array?'
  interger = gets.chomp
  if array.include?(interger)
    array.delete(interger)
    print array
  end

  if interger != array.include?(interger)
    puts 'try another value'
    enter_integer
  end
end

first_array
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess your listing above is missing `def enter_integer` at the top.

The key thing you're missing here is the `else` keyword:

```rb
if array.include?(integer)
  array.delete(integer)
  print array
else
  puts 'try another value'
  enter_integer
end
```

It sounds like you want to loop instead of trying only twice, so:

```rb
def enter_integer
  puts 'what would you like to remove from array?'
  integer = gets.chomp
  if array.include?(integer)
    array.delete(integer)
    print array
    return true  # return keyword is probably unecessary here
  else
    return false  # return keyword is probably unecessary here
  end
end

def first_array
  ...
  result = enter_integer
  while !result do
    enter_integer
  end
  ...
end
```

You'll probably also want a way to exit the loop without adding an acceptable integer.

Answer (score 0):

### Invalid Comparison

Among other issues, this piece of code doesn't do what you think:

```
# "interger" is the spelling given in the OP
if interger != array.include?(interger)
```

[Array#include?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) returns a Boolean, so your if-statement isn't really performing a useful comparison. Your logic is not only inverted, it's also basically doing this, which will always be true except when `integer = true`.

```
integer != (true || false)
```

### Recommended Refactoring

Assuming you populate your initial array via user input (or any other means), you can refactor like so:

```
# populate initial array any way you like
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

loop do
  puts "Current array: #{array}"
  print 'Enter integer to delete ("X" to exit): '
  input = gets.chomp.upcase

  # you need a break condition to exit the loop    
  break if input == 'X'

  # make sure your value is cast as Integer
  input = input.to_i

  # use ternary operator to handle the result
  array.include?(input) ?
    array.delete(input) : STDERR.puts("invalid: #{input}")
end

# return your ending array
array
```

There are certainly other ways to do this, but using [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) with an explicit [break](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/doc/keywords_rdoc.html) condition seems easiest to me. Your mileage may vary.